# How to connect to twitter using socialauth in android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, socialauth

I am using 3pillar socialauth to write an app that connect with 3 sites - facebook, twitter and google+. While login with facebook is working perfectly fine I am having issues with twitter. I get the following message - `org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthConfigurationException: Application keys are not correct. The server running the application should be same that was registered to get the keys.`
If I use the default keys provided with the samples the app works perfectly fine. How do I resolve this issue? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting similar issue for linkedin. Is it resolved for you? how you resolved it?

Comment: Not exactly. We decided to not implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter login with `SocialAuth` works perfectly (I've done it). Please ensure that you have done all of the following:

**1.** You have created an app in the Twitter account of your client/company, and the consumer key & consumer secret used in your Android app are the same as those you got from your Twitter app.

**2.** In your Twitter app, you have set the access level to either `Read and write` or `Read, write, and direct messages`.

**3.** You *must* provide a callback URL in your Twitter app.

**References:**

**1.** [Step by Step Guide to Get Twitter consumer key and secrets.](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/wiki/Twitter)

Comment: How do I determine the callback url? Because now I am getting org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.twitter.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: Try `callback://twitter`.

Comment: It didn't work. The error says 'Error
Validation failed: Not a valid URL format'

Comment: I have put a placeholder url but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried this with SDK version 3.2? I get the same error, the callback set in the API console is the same used in addCallback() method. Getting the keys is simple so I cant figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: @Pankaj: Hi ... I request you to mark this as the correct answer and upvote it ... thanks :)

Comment: @ ZygoteInit: Hi, could you please clarify what the callback url should be? I tried callback://twitter and from Twitter also get Error. Validation failed: Not a valid URL format

Comment: Ok, I added a default url (the website url) and it worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Zygotelnit, I suggest you remove your original suggestion to Pankaj of trying callback://twitter or provide some reference link. (Trying that was a waste of time for me.) I'm upvoting your answer because you emphasize that a callback url must be given.

Comment: Ok, I suppose `callback://twitter` is wrong after all, and I now remember that I too had used the website URL for callback redirect :)